# On Android Q, how do I get vertical coordinates of the left navigation gesture zone?

Tags: android, gesture, android-10.0

On Android Q, when gesture navigation is enabled, most of the left (and right) edge of the screen is reserved to the back gesture. It conflicts with a Navigation drawer I'm using. While the newest androidx libraries include support for opening the drawer with a long press at the edge + swipe, this gesture is too unreliable—it often produces long taps on inner views or back gestures instead of opening the drawer.

As the Navigation Drawer is a very often used element in the app, I want to give the user the option to have an area on the bottom of the display where they can open the drawer normally. I can use [`View#setSystemGestureExclusionRects`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSystemGestureExclusionRects(java.util.List%3Candroid.graphics.Rect%3E)) for that. It limits the exclusion zone to 200dp, which isn't that much. I noticed that the left gesture zone doesn't start at the bottom of the screen, it starts somewhere above the bottom gesture zone—there's a space on the left edge of the screen where no gesture zone applies. To maximize the 200dp I'm getting, I want to place the exclusion zone exactly at the bottom of the gesture zone. To do this, I need to find the exact vertical coordinates of the gesture zone. How can I do this?

Alternatively, can I get more than 200dp while keeping the regular navigation gestures?

Comment: there is no way for more than 200dp. for gesture part you probably can use insets

Comment: won't insets give me only the “thickness” of the gesture zones, not their position on the screen?